# Looping through TextView and setting the size

Tags: java, android, loops, textview

I'm trying to loop through a specified list of sizes and change the size of the text in my TextView accordingly. How can I go about doing this properly?

```
public void TextBigger(View view) {
    int[] textViewSizes = new int[] {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
    for(int i=0; i < textViewSizes.length; i++) {
        text_View.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: *How can I go about doing this properly?* Can you elaborate whats wrong and what you really want

Comment: Sorry. I basically want to change the size of the text every time the user presses the button. It should loop through a list of specified sizes.

Comment: I think you mean text_View.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, **textViewSizes[i]** ); but this is pointless since it changes the same textview all the time. in the end the text size will always be the last index. do you also have other textviews?

Comment: Right.  Hmm... Still doesn't seem to be working though. It just decreases my size once and every time I press the button thereafter it does nothing. i needs to update after each press or something.

Comment: The textsize will always be 20. do you want it to change every time you click the button to the next size?

Comment: @WalterM Yes that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: try using spannable string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//make these class scope
int currentTextSize = 0;
int[] textViewSizes = new int[] {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

public void TextBigger(View view) {
    if(currentTextSize < textViewSizes.length - 1)
        currentTextSize++;
    text_View.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textViewSizes[currentTextSize]);
}
```